# Counter net decidability

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, decidability, formal-languages, automata-theory

Let  one Deterministic Counter Net ($\mathrm{1DCN}$), which is a finite-state automata  where every state is complete means all states has transition of all input symbols and their respective weight value.

For example,  $\mathrm{1DCN}$ below has input symbols $\sigma=\{a,b,c,d\}$,
[image]

and a Non-deterministic Counter Net ($\mathrm{1CN}$)  which is not necessarily complete, For example $\mathrm{1CN}$ is,
[image]

Also both the machines calculates total weight value along the path of the given string. And total weight value is called the counter value. And the string is accepted when counter value $\geq0.$

Lets say, the input symbols belong to the set $\sigma=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and the counter value is, say $x\geq0.$ Considering above $\mathrm{1CN}$ , the string $cab$ is accepted because the calculated counter value is $1-1+0=0$ but the string $dab$ is not accepted because calculated counter value is $0-1+0=-1,$which  is negative.

**My question**:

- Given any  Deterministic Counter Net ($\mathrm{1DCN}$) called $\mathrm{D}$ and Non-deterministic Counter Net ($\mathrm{1CN}$)  called $\mathrm{A}$ which satisfies their above properties, is $L(\mathrm{A})=L(\mathrm{D})$  decidable or not? How to Write an algorithm for it?
  I know that it is undecidable but unable to prove.

**References**

Piotr Hofman, Patrick Totzke "[Trace Inclusion for One-Counter Nets Revisited](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.5157)".

Piotr Hofman, Richard Mayr, Patrick Totzke "[Decidability of Weak Simulation on One-counter Nets](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.4104)".

Comment: "The proposition $L(A) = L(D)$ is undecidable" is a meaningless statement; there is no input to the algorithmic problem, so either it is true or not, and so either the algorithm saying "yes" or the one saying "no" solves it. I really do not know what you mean by "How to write an algorithm for equivalence that is undecidable?". This I cannot parse as a question about what you wrote. Could you clarify?

Comment: I mean  the decidability of 1CN v.s. 1DCN equivalence. And how to prove it. Any algorithm.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly is the decision problem you want to ask about? The question you have asked seems to be about the particular automata A and D, and is therefore trivial as a decision problem, as Carl-Fredrik states. But in your comment you suggest that you have in mind another more general decision problem. Please edit your question to state exactly the decision problem you have in mind, in particular specifying the input and desired output. (It is a common beginner's error in decidability questions to be sloppy with such formalism, but the answers often depend on the details.)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I editted the question, actually I asking for the general 1DCN and 1CN, not the particular automata.

Comment: I would suggest further edits to clarify that your A and D pictures are merely examples of the kinds of machines you want to consider, and so question for those machines is one instance of the general decision problem you inquire about. Your question will become much clearer that way.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins please check and let me know.

Comment: Well, I'd say you haven't explained the question very well—it is a badly asked question. Most people here, even many of those very familiar with finite state automata, don't necessarily know about counter machines. You should explain them a little. Your machine D seems very silly and so it isn't a good example. Your question has a very bad latex typo. You still haven't properly described the decision problem in terms of input/output. Rather, you mix up the decision problem itself with the question whether the decision problem is computably decidable.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I hope I have editted correctly now.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You still conflate the decision problem with the question whether the decision problem is computably decidable. The decision problem is: given a determinist counter net D and a nondeterministic counternet A, answer Yes if L(D)=L(A) and otherwise No. The question you want to ask is:  Is that decision problem computably decidable? And the introduction makes no sense, since you say "Let D..." as though D is fixed for the question, but in the decision problem D is a variable, able to take on any value as an input to the decision problem. And you still don't explain counters.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins  I have given more explanation and please suggest any hints.

Comment: You have indeed improved the question, so I thank you. I shall not make any more suggestions, although of course there remains room for improvement in any question or answer.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins please give any suggestions how to develop a algorithm.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda I improved the question, please give hints how to write algorithm.

Comment: I have attempted, in a [non-answer answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/451105/17064) to rewrite the question to make it understandable. @AlokMaity please clarify whether this matches the definitions you wanted to make, and which one(s) of the questions 1–4 I list you wanted to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a partial answer (see note 2 below), but mostly an attempt to rephrase the question into something both meaningful and understandable, so that hopefully someone can answer it.

Let $\sigma$ be a finite set, also known as the *alphabet*, and $\sigma^*$ the set of *words* on $\sigma$, i.e., the free monoid on $\sigma$ (consisting of finite sequences of elements of $\sigma$).

A **$(\mathbb{Z},\max,+)$-weighted finite automaton** on $\sigma$ is given by a finite set $Q$ of *states*, an element $q_0 \in Q$ known as the *initial state*, a subset $F \subseteq Q$ known as the *accepting states*, and a finite subset $\delta \subseteq Q \times \sigma \times \mathbb{Z} \times Q$ known as *transitions* of the automaton (read $(q,x,v,q') \in \delta$ as “the automaton can jump from state $q$ to state $q'$ while consuming symbol $x$ with multiplicity $v$).

For such an automaton, we define the **multiplicity** of the word $w = x_1\cdots x_n \in \sigma^*$ to be the max of the $v_1+\cdots+v_n$ ranging over all accepting paths, that is, all $(q_1,\ldots,q_n)$ and $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ such that $q_n\in F$ and $(q_{i-1},x_i,v_i,q_i)\in\delta$ for $1\leq i\leq n$ (note that $q_0$ is the initial state defined with the automaton), or $-\infty$ if there is no accepting path at all.  The **language** $L(A)$ defined by the automaton $A$ is the set of words having nonnegative multiplicity (i.e., such that there exists an accepting path with $v_1+\cdots+v_n \geq 0$).

[*Note on edit:* I had initially written this for automata with weights in the integer ring $(\mathbb{Z},+,\times)$ (so we take the sum of the $v_1\cdots v_n$).  But I realize, after re-reading the question, that the indended meaning is for the weights to be in the *tropical* semiring $(\mathbb{Z}\cup\{-\infty\},\max,+)$ (we can forget about the weight $-\infty$ by simply omitting the transition).  I'm sorry if this may have caused further confusion.]

We say that the automaton is **deterministic** when $\delta$ is actually a function $Q\times\sigma \to \mathbb{Z}\times Q$ (that is, for all $(q,x) \in Q\times \sigma$ there is a unique $(v,q') \in \mathbb{Z}\times Q$ such that $(q,x,v,q') \in \delta$).

**Question 1:** Is it true that, for every $(\mathbb{Z},\max,+)$-weighted finite automaton $A$ there is a deterministic one $D$ such that $L(D) = L(A)$?

**Question 2:** If the answer to question 1 is “no”, is there an algorithm which, given $A$, decides whether there is such a $D$?

**Question 3:** Is there an algorithm which, given $A$ for which there is such a $D$, returns such a $D$?

**Question 4** (added following JDH's comment): Is there an algorithm which, given $A$ and $D$, with $D$ deterministic, decides whether $L(A) = L(D)$ holds?  [*Update*: see note 2 below.]

**Note** that if we consider the question of *unweighted* automata instead (i.e., all weights are assumed to be $0$), then the answer to questions 1 and 3 is “yes”: in this setup, to construct $D$ we consider the powerset of the set of states of $A$, and create a transition $(\mathbf{q},x,\mathbf{q}')$ in $D$ when $\mathbf{q}'$ is the set of $q'$ such that the transition $(q,x,q')$ exists in $A$ for some $q\in \mathbf{q}$; the accepting states of $D$ are those that contain some accepting state of $A$, and the initial state of $D$ is the singleton $\{q_0\}$ of the accepting state of $A$.  This is a classical construction from automata theory (“determinization”).  The answer to question 4 is also “yes” in this case (the argument proceeds by first determinizing as just explained, then *minimizing* the resulting automata, and the simply comparing them).  But the fact that we can have negative multiplicities completely changes things.

**Note 2:** the answer to question 4 (for $(\mathbb{Z},\max,+)$-weighted automata) is negative, in fact even if $D$ is the trivial automaton which accepts every word (one state, both initial and finite, and no transition) so that $L(D) = \sigma^*$, there is no algorithm to decide whether $L(A) = \sigma^*$.  See Almagor, Boker & Kupferman, [“What's decidable about weighted automata?”](https://faculty.runi.ac.il/udiboker/files/ABK20.pdf), theorem 4.1 (taking care that since they use $(\mathbb{Z}\cup\{+\infty\},\min,+)$ as tropical semiring instead of $(\mathbb{Z}\cup\{-\infty\},\max,+)$ as above, the set of words of multiplicity $<1$ in their sense is the set of words of multiplicity $\geq 0$ in the above sense).

Comment: I thought he was trying to ask merely whether the decision problem of whether a given non-deterministic counter machine D accepted the same language as a given determinisitic counter machine A, was decidable. But your interpretation is quite different from this.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Indeed, I may have misinterpreted the question (my main goal was to clarify the definition of weighted automata, and I may have too hastily extrapolated that the question was about transposing the standard result on unweighted automata which I recalled in the note).

Comment: @Gro-Tsen, I have tried to write the algorithm but I am not unable to handle the counter value, so you need to verify my algorithm and make necessary edit , and please inside the algorithm please insert ,where to write and how to handle counter(weight) value. My algorithm is [here ](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17EypjMIySXGu8p0jEYB6SAOpbASbUAlD/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I also have tried to write the algorithm in different way,I don't know it is right or not. So please check it and I am not unable to handle the counter value, so you need to verify my algorithm and make necessary edit , and same problem as algorithm1, where to insert counter value inside algorithm, please edit it, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17J1I6pY91HcGw-KAh3w-MmzP2VjsJVTt/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, please look above in my comments what I have tried to write the algorithm so far and please give feedback where I need to improve.

Comment: @AlokMaity You still haven't asked a clear question, and people are starting to lose patience. I have attempted to ask your question *as you should have asked it* above, and I have proposed 4 possible questions which may or may not be yours (and provided an answer to question 4). Your job is now to tell us if I have correctly interpreted the definitions, and which of question(s) 1–4 I am proposing is yours. Maybe once we know the question *and only then* we can start looking into an answer.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I need all the answers and specially need algorithm for 4 it as JoelDavidHamkins stated in first comment.

Comment: @AlokMaity OK, well, concerning question 4, it is answered by the reference to Almagor, Boker & Kupferman cited in my “note 2”.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen please elaborate note2 more, why you use tropical semiring?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen, how to proof that it(question 4) is undecidable? You mentioned just example. I need the proof.

Comment: What do you mean “example”? The paper I linked to has a proof. I gave a precise reference. I don't understand what more you want.

Comment: I use the tropical semiring because I think that's what you're doing in your question (without actually saying it): taking the max of the sum $v_1+\cdots+v_n$ over all accepting paths. That's why I asked you to read my reformulation of your question carefully, and tell me whether it captures your question, and, if not, where it differs. Is it or is it not what you are asking about? (And if not, you need to describe *extremely precisely* how the automata you're interested in differ from the ones I described.)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I don't understand the proof pdf, they actually consider N-WFA and compare two non-deterministic WFA, but need the proof of one deterministic Z-wfa D, and one non-deterministic Z-wfa 
A equivalence proof. Would you please elaborate little bit.

Comment: Their theorem 4.1 states that the universality of a nondeterministic $ℤ$-WFA $A$ (i.e., deciding $L(A)=\sigma^*$) is already undecidable, so even if $D$ is the *trivial* automaton the problem is undecidable: obviously saying that $L(A)=\sigma^*$ is undecidable is stronger than saying that $L(A)=L(D)$ is undecidable. So I hope it is now clear how their theorem 4.1 answers question 4. If you have questions about the proof of their theorem 4.1, I can't answer them, but I think this is not suitable for MathOverflow: maybe try cstheory instead (but only with a very *precise* question).

Comment: @Gro-Tsen  you please answer the question1, q2, q3.

Comment: I don't know the answer to 1,2,3 (or I would have posted it).

Comment: @Gro-Tsen you please edit your answer by inserting the above your comments and you give some concepts Q1, Q3, Q4 but what about Q2?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen for deterministic function you use Q, if I use non deterministic then it should be $2^Q$ for every Q?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. No, I denote $Q$ the set of sates of an automaton, whether deterministic or not.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen you said for deterministic function---"""We say that the automaton is deterministic when δ
 is actually a function Q×σ→Z×Q
 (that is, for all (q,x)∈Q×σ
 there is a unique (v,q′)∈Z×Q
 such that (q,x,v,q′)∈δ
). ""  My question if write same thing for non-deterministic function so would it be Q×σ→Z×2^Q
 (that is, for all (q,x)∈2^Q×σ
 there is a unique (v,q′)∈Z×2^Q
 such that (q,x,v,q′)∈δ
)? Am I correct?

Comment: @AlokMaity No, this is not equivalent because what you have written requires that all transitions starting from a given state $q$ and labeled by a given symbol $x$ have the same multiplicity $v$ (contradicting the second drawing in your question), unlike what I wrote where this is permitted. But even without multiplicities (where the two formulations become equivalent), this would be strange: you don't normally write a relation $\delta\subseteq X\times X'$ as a function $X \to 2^{X'}$ unless there's a good reason to.

Comment: Also, I think if you have questions about elementary mathematical concepts such as reformulating a relation as a function or vice versa, MathOverflow is not the right place for them: MathOverflow is for research level mathematics. Questions 1–4 as I have written them are adequate for this place, but now that the discussion has become so confused they are unlikely to receive much attention, unfortunately. The very tedious discussion leading to a correct formulation of the question, on the other hand, is out of place here.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Counter Nets are not the same as Weighted automata. They are in fact very different, because in CN the counter values need to always remain above 0. As it turns out, this makes a huge difference. So your implementation  not right properly.

Comment: What do you mean by “need” to always remain above zero? For the word to be accepted? If so, this is what I wrote above (I defined $L(A)$ as the set of words with multiplicity $≥0$ as this seemed to be what you wanted). Or for all words? In this case, this contradicts your own example in the second image where you give the example of the word $dab$ which has $<0$ multiplicity value. ⁂ Whatever the case, this illustrates the problem: **you never made the question clear**. I have attempted to state it precisely as you should have, and asked you if this was indeed your question.

Comment: So, either what I have written above (and partially answered) is, indeed, your question, or it is not. Only you can tell. If it is *not*, then your job is to write your question in the same mathematically precise language that I used, not using drawings and examples (or at least, not just that) but using a clear and mathematically precise definition of what kind of automata you are considering and what the language $L(A)$ is.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen A run of an OCN is accepting if the counter values (what you call "multiplicity") in the entire​ run remains above 0. Not just the sum at the end.
This may sound like a small difference, but it's not.
See the semantics e.g., here:
https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2022/17081/pdf/LIPIcs-CONCUR-2022-18.pdf

Comment: Well, it's very unfortunate that you didn't realize this from the start and specify it in your question, rather than edit it after three days (and 40 comments). At this point, this question is unsalvageable. I suggest you open a new one, but only once you know and understand precisely what it is you want to ask, and are sure you can formulate it in clear, unambiguous and mathematically precise (and self-contained) language. (The last link you give is clear about the semantics, but it seems to answer several questions of undecidability, so I don't know what there's left to ask.)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I also was misunderstood by this question, I apologize, I asked new [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451272/equivalence-between-two-counter-machine) . To protect your this answer I rollback into my old version of this present question.