# Language equivalence between deterministic and non-deterministic counter net

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, decidability, formal-languages, automata-theory

One-Counter Nets (OCNs) are finite-state machines equipped with an integer counter that
cannot decrease below zero and cannot be explicitly tested for zero.

An OCN $A$ over alphabet $\sum$ accepts a word $w \in \sum^*$ from initial counter value $c\in\mathbb{N}$ if there is a run of $A$ on $w$ from an initial state to an accepting state in which the counter,starting from value $c$, does not become negative. Thus, for every counter value $c\in\mathbb{N}$ the OCN $A$ defines a language $L(A,c) \subseteq \sum^*$.

As is the case with many computational models, certain decision problems for deterministic OCNs (OCNs that admit a single legal transition for each state $q$ and letter $\sigma$), denoted DOCNs, are computationally easier than for nondeterministic OCNs.

A one-counter net (OCN) is a finite automaton whose transitions are labelled both by letters and by integer weights. Formally, an OCN is a tuple $A = \langle \sum, Q, s_0, \delta, F\rangle$ where $\sum$ is a finite alphabet, $Q$ is a finite set of states, $s_0 \in Q$ is the initial state, $\delta \subseteq Q × \sum × \mathbb{Z} × Q$ is the set of transitions, and $F \subseteq Q$ are the accepting states. We say that an OCN is **deterministic** if for every $s \in Q, \delta \in \sum,$ there is at most one transition $(s, \sigma, e, s′)$ for some $e ∈ \mathbb{Z}$ and $s′ \in Q$.
For a transition $t = (s, \sigma, e, s′)\in \delta$ we define ***eff***$(t) = e$ to be its (counter) effect.

A path in the OCN is a sequence $\pi= (s_1, \sigma_1, e_1, s_2)(s_2, \sigma_2, e_2, s_3)\dots(s_k, \sigma_k, e_k, s_{k+1})\delta^*.$

Such a path $\pi$ is a cycle if $s_1 = s_{k+1}$, and is a simple cycle if no other cycle is a proper infix of it. We say that the path $\pi$ reads the word $\sigma_1\sigma_2\dots\sigma_k \in \sum^∗.$

The effect of $\pi$ is ***eff***$(\pi) =\Sigma_{i=1}^k e_i$, and its *nadir*, denoted ***nadir***$(\pi)$, is the minimal effect of any prefix of $\pi$(note that the nadir is non-positive, since ***eff***$(\epsilon) = 0)$.
A configuration of an OCN is a pair $(s, v) \in Q × \mathbb{N}$ comprising a state and a non-negative integer. For a letter $\sigma \in \sum$ and configurations $(s, v),(s′, v′)$ we write $(s,v)\xrightarrow{\sigma}(s′, v′)$ if there exists $d\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $v′ = v + d$ and $(s, \sigma, d, s′)\in\delta$.
A run of $A$ from initial counter $c$ on a word $w = \sigma_1\sigma_2\dots\sigma_k\in\sum^*$is a sequence of configurations $\rho = (q_0, v_0),(s_1, v_1)\dots(s_k, v_k)$ such that $v_0 = c$ and for every $1 \leq i \leq k$ it holds that $(s_{i−1}, v_{i−1})\xrightarrow{\sigma_i}(s_i, v_i)$. Since configurations may only have a non-negative counter, this enforces that the counter does not become negative.

**My question**:
Is the following problem decidable? (does there exist an algorithm that solves it for all instances)

- **Input:** Given an $OCN$ $A$ and a $DOCN$ $D$,
- **Question:** is $L(A,0)=L(D,0)$$?$

**References**

Shaull Almagor, Asaf Yeshurun [Determinization of One-Counter Nets](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2022/17081/pdf/LIPIcs-CONCUR-2022-18.pdf)

Piotr Hofman, Patrick Totzke "[Trace Inclusion for One-Counter Nets Revisited](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.5157)".

Piotr Hofman, Richard Mayr, Patrick Totzke "[Decidability of Weak Simulation on One-counter Nets](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.4104)".

Comment: In the comments of [the previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/451105/17064), you linked to [this paper by Almagor and Yeshurun](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2022/17081/pdf/LIPIcs-CONCUR-2022-18.pdf) which is precisely about this sort of questions, so I don't understand why you don't link it here. At the very least, you should imitate their style of writing the definition (and/or the one I had suggested in the previous question) because, once again, what you wrote is more examples than actual definition.

Comment: Additionally, you ought to explain why theorem 6 in [the aforementioned paper by Almagor and Yeshurun](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2022/17081/pdf/LIPIcs-CONCUR-2022-18.pdf) doesn't answer your question, because as far as I understand it you're asking exactly the question that their theorem 6 answers, so, again, I'm confused!

Comment: @Gro-Tsen  "one-Deterministic Counter Net " Hyperlink is your intended pdf, I already given. And I am not asking theorem 6, I am asking equivalence between deterministic and non-deterministic OCN. I hope you understand me what I actually want from previous question, if you have any doubt regarding question, you are welcome to edit my question. In your previous answer only one mistake i.e. counter issue at every state should be 0 or above 0.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen in their theorem 6 , in 0-Det,L(A, 0)=L(D, 0), both have inital counter value 0, but in my case counter value 0 or above 0.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen The counter value when for both the machines  are  accepting the same string should be anything. That's also a difference from weighted automata: it's a Boolean model, either accept or reject. The end counter value is irrelevant.

Comment: First, this is not very important, but when you cite a paper you need to name the authors and the complete title (and ideally the place where published and the date, if published), and link to an official PDF, not to a copy of the PDF on some Google Drive file of yours. Second, and this is more important, it is still not clear where and what the quantifiers are in your question: are you asking whether the question “**given** $A$ an OCN, $D$ a DOCN, $c$ and $c'$ integers, **is** $L(A,c) = L(D,c')$?” is decidable? or something else?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I **suspect** this is an open question, because in the paper [“Parametrized Universality Problems for One-Counter Nets” by Almagor, Boker, Hofman and Totzke](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.03435), at the end of the introduction (“related work”), they state that ①“language inclusion is
undecidable for \[…\] OCNs” whereas ②“universality is decidable for the special case of OCNs”: if the answer to your question were known they would surely have mentioned it (as it lies between ① and ②) — since they did not, I **suspect** it is unknown.

Comment: What I just said is that I don't know and that I *suspect* that nobody knows. I can't give you ideas.

Comment: @AlokMaity This may be a language issue, but saying things like "give me ideas" comes across as quite demanding, and will almost certainly have the opposite effect. If you write a clear, mathematically precise question, then people will engage with your question if they have ideas to give. Otherwise, you may end up with comment chains of 40+ comments (like on your previous question), and having to expend that much time and patience to figure out what you mean (like @ Gro-Tsen has valiantly done!) is **very** dissuading to anyone who might be able to answer your question.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda I have written it mathematically.

Comment: In my view, the question conflates the decision problem with the question whether it is decidable. I had objected to this on the previous version of the question, but this objection was never adequately addressed and is repeated in this question. It may seem a picky point, but in my experience, for sensible discussion one must formulate the decision problem correctly. For any fixed A, D, c, c', the question "is L(A)=L(D)?" as stated by the OP has a Y/N answer—each instance computable by a trivial algorithm. But that isn't what OP wants to know, and so the question has not been properly asked.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I restructured the question.

Comment: It's a little better, but still not there. The key aspect for me is that decidability is ONE question, whereas the decision problem is a scheme of infinitely many questions ranging over all possible inputs. To specify the decidability question is to state explicitly the nature of the input and the desired correct answer. The decidability question is to ask whether there is a computable procedure which answers correctly in all those cases, giving the correct output for any of the allowed given inputs. Decidability is about a uniform computability issue, not a case-by-case computability issue.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Very helpful! Both of these problems are variants of the determinization problem, which I've already studied (in the paper1 that I mentioned in question).https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.5157

The problem at hand is:
Given an OCN A and a DOCN D, is L(A,0)=L(D,0)? See the updated question.

Comment: The newly edited question seems to be a relatively clear statement of the decision problem that your question is concerned with. But I believe that this is not your actual question. After all, what kind of answer are we to give to the question you have asked? For which A and D are we to answer? Your actual question, I think, is the question whether the decision problem defined by that question is computably decidable. For this reason, unfortunately, the current formulation continues to conflate the decision problem with the question whether it is decidable.

Comment: To illustrate what I am talking about, consider the problem of primality testing. The decision problem is: given a number p, decide if it is prime. A 2nd natural question is: what is the computational complexity of primality testing? Notice that these are two different inquiries. One is a scheme of questions about numbers and whether they are prime, and the other asks about the running time of algorithms correctly answering all instances of the 1st problem. You have a similar situation, a decision problem and an inquiry about its complexity, but your posts unfortunately mix these together.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins For which A and D are we to answer? -- The A and D are which are I define in my question. I need one  answer which  explain computably decidable and also decidable.

Comment: Well, I wish you good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that as far as I'm aware, this question is open.
It is however very close to ones that are settled. I provide some more detail below.

As you've correctly pointed out, the decidability status of decision problems relating to counter automata
often depends on the presence of non-determinism, but also on the acceptance criterion.
The initial counter value should not matter as long as it is fixed (you can always build another automaton in the same class that sets the initial value via some initial chain of states. This will change the language of the automaton but will not change the decidability status of most decision problems). I will assume below that the initial counter is $0$ always.

There are three natural ways to define accepting runs, and thus the language of the automaton:

1. **Trace semantics**: A run is accepting if the effect of every prefix is greater equal to $0$. So you simply don't starve. Let's write $T(A)$ for the set of words in $\Sigma^*$ so that the automaton $A$ (with some fixed initial state) has some accepting run on them. This is the semantics your original is about.
2. **Coverability semantics**: A run is accepting if it does not (starve as above) and ends in a "final" state. This is a designated subset of the control states, fixed as part of the automaton's definition. Let's write $C(A)$ for the resulting coverability language of $A$.
3. **Reachability semantics**: A run is accepting if it satisfies 1), 2) and ends in counter value $0$. Let's write $R(A)$ for the corresponding language of $A$.

##### Let's consider the reachability semantics first.

Here, the language universality problem ($R(A) = \Sigma^*$?) is already undecidable ([0], theorem 10).
Since you can easily build a *deterministic* finite automaton, and therefore OCN, with $\Sigma^*$, the undecidability of universality transfers to both inclusion and equivalence.

##### For the coverability and trace semantics,

universality remains decidable [1,2], yet inclusion is not [3].
In fact, [2,3] are written solely in terms of trace semantics but the argument for the upper bounds (decidability and complexity) in [2] works the same for coverability semantics, and the undecidability in [3] trivially transfers from the easier trace inclusion ($T(A)\subseteq T(B)$?) to coverability language inclusion ($C(A)\subseteq C(B)$?) by making all states final.
The argument for the undecidability of trace inclusion also works if the system $A$ on the left is deterministic, but *not* if $B$ on the RHS is deterministic.

You can reduce inclusion to equivalence by a small trick:
to check if $T(A)\subseteq T(B)$ you can equivalently check if $T(A') = T(B')$ for the modified automata where
$A' \rightarrow A$,
$A' \rightarrow B$
and $B'\rightarrow B$.
(after one step, $B'$ continues as $B$ and $A'$ can continue either as $A$ or $B$).
This will *make* $A'$ non-deterministic. It shows that trace (and thus cover) equivalence $T(A)=T(B)$ is undecidable for two non-deterministic OCN.

##### Your question

Trace equivalence ($T(A) = T(B)$?) between a OCN $A$ and a DOCN $B$, is open as fact as I'm aware.
Notice that you **cannot** decide it by checking two-way inclusion
because, as argued above, the inclusion $T(B)\subseteq T(A)$ is undecidable.

**Remark 1:**
The inclusion $T(A)\subseteq T(B)$ is in fact decidable if $B$ is deterministic. This can be shown in several ways, for example by checking simulation preorder [4] (if the RHS is deterministic then language inclusion coincides with simulation).
Alternatively, you can complement $B$ into a one-counter *automaton* $B'$ (that has explicit zero-testing transitions) then checking emptiness for $A\times B'$ via [5].
This will also work for a slightly larger class of "history-deterministic" automaton the RHS [6].

**Remark 2:**
If you consider languages of infinite words,
these are significantly more complex, both topologically and in terms of decision problems.
The languages recognised by OCN accepting by infinitely often visiting final states,
are not even Borel [7] and have and undecidable universality problem [8].
So in this case again, the equivalence of infinite trace languages is undecidable.

I hope this is useful; thanks for the very interesting question!  Best wishes, P.

---

[0]: *Petri nets and regular languages*. Rüdiger Valk, Guy Vidal-Naquet
https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-0000(81)90067-2

[1]: *Petri Nets and Regular Processes* Petr Jančar, Javier Esparza, Faron Moller;  https://doi.org/10.1006/jcss.1999.1643

[2]: *Trace inclusion for one-counter nets revisited* Piotr Hofman, and Patrick Totzke https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2017.05.009

[3]: *Decidability of Weak Simulation on One-Counter Nets*. Piotr Hofman, Richard Mayr, and Patrick Totzke. http://doi.org/10.1109/LICS.2013.26

[4]: *Simulation Over One-Counter Nets*. Piotr Hofman, Sławomir Lasota, Richard Mayr, and Patrick Totzke
(The paper appeared in LMCS, I cannot post more than 7 links apparently, sorry)

[5]: *Reachability in Petri nets with inhibitor arcs.* Klaus Reinhardt. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.entcs.2008.12.042

[6]: *On History-Deterministic One-Counter Nets*. Adityaf Prakash & K. S. Thejaswini
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-031-30829-1_11

[7]: *Büchi VASS recognise w-languages that are $\Sigmaˆ1_1$-complete*. Michal Skrzypczak. https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.09658

[8]: *On Büchi One-Counter Automata*.
Böhm, Stanislav; Göller, Stefan; Halfon, Simon ;Hofman, Piotr
https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2017/7019/